# How to rebuild master-slave multi-core with schema.xml from old verison in Solr 5.5

Tags: solr, schema, multicore, master-slave

I've built 2 cores with schema.xml on 1 master and 2 slaves in old-version Solr. Both master and slave use solrcore.properties to indicate their roles. e.g. for slave (note:for master, I just reverse the true/false), it's:

```
enable.master=false
enable.slave=true
#define master url
MASTER_CORE_URL=192.168.1.222:8983/corea_SE
POLL_TIME=00:00:60
```

and in solrconfig.xml, I define the roles detail, e.g:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
    <!-- Use solrcore.properties to switch the role for node -->
    <lst name="master">
       <str name="enable">${enable.master:false}</str>
       <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
       <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
       <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="slave">
        <str name="enable">${enable.slave:false}</str>
        <str name="masterUrl">http://${MASTER_CORE_URL}/${solr.core.name}/replication</str>
        <str name="pollInterval">${POLL_TIME}</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I want to rebuild this construction in Solr 5.5 but I find no such example or instructions in either Solr 5.5 download pack or [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide). Solr 5.5 doesn't even have any examples with schema.xml or master-slave. How can I do this? Is there any doc or url that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
<!-- ### This tells Solr we're using manually-edit schema.xml ### -->
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

in Solrconfig.xml.